# Flatlist undefined is not an object React-native

Tags: react-native, babeljs, expo

I am building a simple React-native app with Expo for rating Github repositories and ran into a nasty issue. When I am trying to render a list of the repositories with Flatlist it throws me the following error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'repository.fullName'); although my code is pretty much identical to the one in React-native docs. Here is the RepositoryList.jsx where the Flatlist is being rendered:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RepositoryItem from './RepositoryItem'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  separator: {
    height: 10,
  },
});

const repositories = [
  {
    id: 'rails.rails',
    fullName: 'rails/rails',
    description: 'Ruby on Rails',
    language: 'Ruby',
    forksCount: 18349,
    stargazersCount: 45377,
    ratingAverage: 100,
    reviewCount: 2,
    ownerAvatarUrl: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/4223?v=4',
  },
  {
    id: 'reduxjs.redux',
    fullName: 'reduxjs/redux',
    description: 'Predictable state container for JavaScript apps',
    language: 'TypeScript',
    forksCount: 13902,
    stargazersCount: 52869,
    ratingAverage: 0,
    reviewCount: 0,
    ownerAvatarUrl: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/13142323?v=4',
  }
];

const ItemSeparator = () => <View style={styles.separator} />;

const RepositoryList = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={repositories}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
      renderItem={({repository}) => <RepositoryItem repository={repository}/> }
    />
  );
};

export default RepositoryList
```

and RepositoryItem.jsx which should be rendered within the Flatlist:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

const RepositoryItem = ({repository}) => {
  return(
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text>Full name:{repository.fullName}</Text>
      <Text>Description:{repository.description}</Text>
      <Text>Language:{repository.language}</Text>
      <Text>Stars:{repository.stargazersCount}</Text>
      <Text>Forks:{repository.forksCount}</Text>
      <Text>Reviews:{repository.reviewCount}</Text>
      <Text>Rating:{repository.ratingAverage}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'darkorange'
  },
});

export default RepositoryItem
```

After doing my research I found that a lot of people have run into this issue too, and apparently it persists since 0.59 (my React-native is on 0.62, Windows). Apparently the error is being cause by a babel module *'@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'* and the solution would be deleting this module from .babelrc, according to this Github thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24421. The problem is that my *babel.config.js* is extremely simple, and I don't see how I can exclude this module from being required for babel to work. My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Perhaps there is a way to exclude it through tweaking babel in node_modules, but this solution seems unlikely. Any help or suggestions regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your problem consists in destructuring `repository` in your `renderItem` method of the `FlatList`.
You cannot just destructure whatever you want, you have to destructure `item` from the Flatlist.

Try this way:

```
const RepositoryList = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={repositories}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RepositoryItem repository={item}/> }
    />
  );
};
```

Or, if you really want to

```
const RepositoryList = () => {
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={repositories}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item: repository }) => <RepositoryItem repository={repository}/> }
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I did not know that this component has these sorts of limitations on what I should call the destructered data.

Comment: Glad it worked! I wouldn't blame it on the `FlatList`, it's just the way JS and destructuring works. Please be sure to check out this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: @Konstantin can you see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246881/style-not-perfect-on-scroller-view-in-react-native