# Style not perfect on scroller view in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, uitableview, react-redux

## Code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import Carsar from './Carsar'

const dummyData =
    [{
        title: 'Get instant loans with approvals',
        uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWo3YRChZ3ADpZ7rEfQu1RvBOu9NMWZIMZBaH-a1CArXqx6nLX',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
        id: 1

    },
    {
        title: 'Get money in wallet or bank account',
        uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQN0NcV2epN147CiVfr_VAwsbU3VO8rJU0BPphfU9CEsVWa-kRX',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
        id: 2
    },
    {
        title: 'Refer & earn exciting gifts',
        uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUbS4LNT8rnIRASXO6LGFSle7Mhy2bSLwnOeqDMivYTb2cgTJg',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
        id: 3
    }]

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.contanier}>
            <Carsar data={dummyData} />
            <View style={styles.btnview}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}>
                <Text>Get Started</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contanier: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    logo: {
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        borderRadius: 50,
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginTop: 20

    },
    btnview:{
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        marginTop:20
    },
    btn: {
        width: 300,
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#009EFF',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        
    }
})
```

Carsar.js

```
const { width, heigth } = Dimensions.get('window')

function infiniteScroll(dataList){
    const numberOfData = dataList.length
    let scrollValue = 0, scrolled = 0

    setInterval(function() {
        scrolled ++;
        if(scrolled < numberOfData)
        scrollValue = scrollValue + width

        else{
            scrollValue = 0
            scrolled = 0
        }

        this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollValue})
        
    }, 3000)
}


const Carsar = ({ data }) => {
    const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0)
    let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width)
    const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(data)

    useEffect(()=> {
        setDataList(data)
        infiniteScroll(dataList)
    })


    if (data && data.length) {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList data={data}
                ref = {(flatList) => {this.flatList = flatList}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                    horizontal
                    pagingEnabled
                    scrollEnabled
                    snapToAlignment="center"
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    decelerationRate={"fast"}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return <CarouselItem item={item} />
                    }}
                    onScroll={Animated.event(
                        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }]
                    )}
                />

                <View style={styles.dotView}>
                    {data.map((_, i) => {
                        let opacity = position.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [i - 1, i, i + 1],
                            outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
                            extrapolate: 'clamp'
                        })
                        return (
                            <Animated.View
                                key={i}
                                style={{ opacity, height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: '#009EFF', margin: 8, borderRadius: 5 }}
                            />
                        )
                    })}

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    console.log('Please provide Images')
    return null
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    dotView: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center',marginBottom:10}
})

export default Carsar
```

here is full [code](https://snack.expo.dev/@gattu/autoscreoll)

here is output I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2UWM.jpg)

## my output

[image]

I'm trying to do but the style does not come perfectly.

I want to like this if the active index dot width is different from the inactive index I give the above output

when i try to increase the active index width but all index dot width increase when I try to decrease the width but all the index width is decrease how can I do that

where is my mistake anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set a style with bigger width according to the selected index.

So basically inside `carsar.js`

```
                <View style={styles.dotView}>
                    {data.map((_, i) => {
                        let opacity = position.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [i - 1, i, i + 1],
                            outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
                            extrapolate: 'clamp'
                        })
                        const selected = selectedIndex === i
                        return (
                            <Animated.View
                                key={i}
                                style={{ opacity, height: 10, width: selected ? 20 : 10, backgroundColor: '#009EFF', margin: 8, borderRadius: 5 }}
                            />
                        )
                    })}

                </View>
```

Please not that you have to do the logic of selecting the index inside of state.

This will not create an animation, it will just change the width. You'd need to create the animation using `reanimated` or react-native's Animated Library

Comment: it's give me this errro  ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: selectedIndex

Comment: yes as I said you need to implement it. Declare a `selectedIndex` variable at the top level

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: Set at the top level `const selectedIndex = 1`, and try it out as an example and then implement your logic for `selectedIndex`.